# Allow one zoomed image at a time

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using a fairly nice zoom-in / zoom-out effect using only CSS and HTML. The issue I am having is that if a user zooms in on two images, both images will be enlarged on the page. This is technically what it should do, however I am wondering how I can disable this effect.

This is what I am looking for: e.g. there are two images on a page. If I zoom in one one image and then zoom in on the other image (while the first image is zoomed), the first image should zoom out to allow the second image to be the only zoomed image on the page. This principle would apply if there were, for example, ten images -- only one image can be zoomed at any time.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

.container img {
width: 100%;
transition: transform 0.25s ease;
cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label > img {
transform: scale(2.5);
cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoomCheck1">
    <label for="zoomCheck1">
    <img src="https://www.vintagevelo.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/DSC_0040-768x512.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoomCheck2">
    <label for="zoomCheck2">
    <img src="https://premium-cycling.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/FAGGIN-Campione-del-mondo-1980s-frameset-7.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML/CSS/JS? You could just query the elements and check it again the `this` that is being clicked, and disable the rest. If that makes sense.

Comment: I updated the HTML CSS, unfortunately I am not using JS for this, though it is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `+` single next selector instead of next all

Note: I recommend using more specific class selectors of some sort, so that these styles don't end up affecting other elements unintentionally, and make the styles more reusable.

Switched to radio elements to only allow one to be checked at a time.  Use "name" to group them.  You can also use name attribute for the selectors.

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('input[type=radio] + label > img')) {
    e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.checked = !e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.checked;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label>img {
  transform: scale(2.5);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

img {
  width: 50px!important;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="zooms" id="zoomCheck1">
  <label for="zoomCheck1">
    <img class="center round-corner" 
         src="https://i.imgur.com/8qmxbHT.jpeg" />
    </label>
  <input type="radio" name="zooms" id="zoomCheck2">
  <label for="zoomCheck2">
    <img class="center round-corner" 
         src="https://i.imgur.com/8qmxbHT.jpeg" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the feedback. I tried running the code snippet but both images zoom if clicked, i.e. they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Are you sure?  It definitely is working for me here.  I've modified it so the images are smaller so it's easier to see.  Make sure you are running the snippet down below in this answer and not the original in your question.  When you say mutually exclusive, do you mean that only one can be selected at any one time?

Comment: Yes, by mutually exclusive I meant that only one image on the page can be zoomed in at a time. So for your image, if I zoom in on one image then zoom in on the other, the first image should zoom out, yielding only one zoomed object at a time.

Comment: Alright, I've modified it to use radio buttons.  Ah hold on, zoom out doesn't work.  Woops

Comment: Great, the one image zoomed at a time works well, but like you said the zoom-out ability is disabled

Comment: Couldn't think of a way to achieve this without Javascript

Comment: Also, depending on what you want to do, other ways to do this are to use label's htmlFor values to get the id of the radio to uncheck.  Another way is to use toggle checkbox values and clear the rest.  And if you don't need input box values, you could just use class toggling on the images.